# Connecting to my website from the LAN

Tags: web-server, port-forwarding

So I initially set up a web server off an old computer.  I bought a domain from google and configured nameservers to point to FreeDNS where I use their dynamic IP service.  I also use LetsEncrypt for an SSL cert.

Question is...when I want to connect to my website from my own network, I can't just type in the URL.  I have to type in my web server's IPv4 LAN address.  It also does not connect through https://.  Is this normal?  Or have I misconfigured something?

When I originally used my CertBot to configure my HTTPS settings, I originally tried from the localhost but it wouldn't connect to the given URL so I had to connect to a different network to run the SSL certificate.

I can connect to the website normally when I'm off my network.  It seems to be similar to how I use ssh when I work remotely/locally (I ssh into the local IP if working locally and I have ports configured to point to this machine if I need to ssh remotely) so I figured it was normal.

This might be very basic and I think it's normal but I'm not sure where to   go about searching for this. But I just want to double check for security purposes since I've never ran my own web server.

Comment: Can you post your site configuration files so we can see why ssl isn't working?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...

It's not that my SSL cert isn't working, it works if I try to connect to the website from off the local network.  I just can't use my URL if I'm on the local network.  Is this still not normal?

Comment: If you can't connect with your fqdn then it's a DNS issue

Answer (score 1):

If the DNS is returning the public IP address, and you are inside your private network, then the behavior you are seeing is fairly common.  This is usually because firewalls don't allow you to connect to the public IP from inside the network.  You usually end up having to configure the firewall to permit it, if at all possible.

You have a few of options, depending on what you have available for you.  You can host an internal DNS server for your domain, and point the DNS records to the internal host IP addresses.

Some firewalls allow you to do DNS conversions. Cisco list this as "DNS Inspection" in the ASA platforms for example. In this situation, the ASA reads the DNS responses, and if the DNS record response matches the public NAT IP, it changes the DNS response to that of the internal server.

Find out if your DNS host supports "views", which allow you to define different DNS responses based on where your DNS request comes from. This will allow you to define different IP responses depending on where are, so you could return your private IP for you, and public for everybody else.

Then there is the good old classic hosts file.  /etc/hosts on linux platforms or c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows.  Add an entry that matches private address and host name.  For example:

```
192.168.0.5    www.mydomain.com
```

Then the last is to find out if your firewall will allow you to create a rule that will allow connections to be routed back inwards when accessing the public IP.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but thank you very much for your response.  So you don't believe this should be of much concern?  It seems like it's just a matter of convenience.